# WFFM error on CD server

Tags: sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

Ours is a sitecore 8.2 update 3 solution.
We installed wffm on CD as per sitecore guide and enabled SwitchMastertoweb config,

Post it, we are getting the below error.

Solutions tried out
1. Removing the reporting section from SwitchMastertoweb.config file.
No luck. same error.
2. Disabling SwitchMastertoweb.config file.Still same error(sounds strange to me but we are getting same error).

Any clue or more solutions to try out
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProviderBase'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProviderBase'.]
   Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplFactoryObjectsProvider.CreateObject(String configPath, Boolean assert) +57
   Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Dependencies.ReportDataProviderWrapper.GetReportDataProviderBase(Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Providers.AnalyticsFormsDataProvider..ctor(ReportDataProviderWrapper reportDataProviderWrapper, ILogger logger, IAnalyticsTracker analyticsTracker, ISettings settings) +86

Comment: Check solution below

Answer (score 1):

Atlast, issue got solved. Along with the above tips mentioned above  we had to enable the below files to make it work. Sitecore.Marketing.TaxonomyCD.config  Sitecore.MarketingCD.config  Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.RepositoriesCD.config